# Inserting a new element in an element?

Tags: javascript, function

I've been trying to figure out how to put an image and a couple more text(s) when this function gets triggered. Like, how do I add images and other text within the "article" that's going to be created. Help?

```
            var newElement = document.createElement("article");

            var node = document.createTextNode(thingContent);

            var attr = document.createAttribute("class");
            attr.value = "thing";
            newElement.appendChild(node);
            newElement.setAttributeNode(attr);
            var x = document.getElementById("things");

            var y = x.getElementsByTagName("article");
            if(y == null){
                x.appendChild(newElement);
            }else{
                x.insertBefore(newElement, y[0]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create "img" elements with "src" attributes, and other text nodes, and call `newElement.appendChild`.

By the way, you can pretty much just use `.setAttribute('name','value')` to set an attribute for any element rather than going through the createAttribute/value/setAttributeNode dance. And, for `'class'`, you can directly set the `.className` property.